# cudaErrorInsufficientDriver: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version

Tags: kubernetes, cuda, gpu, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running GPU instance on GKE when everything is deployed I make the request to the service Above mention error occur
I followed all the step in mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus#ubuntu
This is my DockerFile

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.2-cudnn7-devel

# install nginx
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install nginx vim -y --no-install-recommends
# RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
#     && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

## Setup 

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    python3-dev \
    python3-pip \
    python3-wheel \
    python3-setuptools && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/archives/*

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -U install setuptools pip
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir cupy_cuda102==8.0.0rc1 scipy optuna

COPY requirements.txt start.sh run.py uwsgi.ini utils.py /opt/app/
COPY shading_characteristics /opt/app/shading_characteristics

WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade 'sentry-sdk[flask]'
RUN pip install uwsgi -I --no-cache-dir

EXPOSE 5000

## Start the server, giving permissions for script
# COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx
RUN chmod +x ./start.sh 
RUN chmod -R 777 /root
CMD ["./start.sh"]
```

Comment: from [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus) "**The latest supported CUDA version is 10.0** on both COS (1.11.5+) and Ubuntu (1.11.8-gke.4+, 1.12.6-gke.6+)."

Answer (score 3):

**Edit (May 2021)**

GKE now officially supports NVIDIA driver version `450.102.04`, which support `CUDA 10.2`.
Please note that GKE 1.19.8-gke.1200 and higher is required.

---

As you can see in Nvidia's [website](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html#binary-compatibility__table-toolkit-driver), `CUDA 10.2` requires Nvidia driver version >= 440.33.

Since the latest Nvidia driver available officially [in GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus#ubuntu) is `418.74`, the newest `CUDA` version you can use is `10.1` at the moment.

If your application, or other dependencies such as PyTorch, can function properly with `CUDA 10.1`, the fastest solution will be to downgrade your base Docker image with `CUDA 10.1`.

There are [unofficial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-engine-accelerators/issues/119) ways to install newer Nvidia Driver versions on GKE nodes running COS, but if it's not a must for you - I'd stick to the official and supported GKE method and use 10.1.

Comment: Please note that `CUDA 10.1` is not supported at this moment in GKE. I tried this out myself, and when using `CUDA 10.1`, the `nvidia-installer` doesn't seem to be installing CUDA properly. Apparently, it is not because the latest Nvidia Driver is `418.74`, that GKE supports `CUDA 10.1`. Besides, it is also clearly denoted in the docs as @Robert Crovella says that the latest supported CUDA version is `10.0`.

Comment: The GKE docs says it only supports 10.0 but according to https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html#binary-compatibility__table-toolkit-driver NVIDIA driver version `418.74` supports CUDA `10.1`